# TimeMachine backup gets stuck during "Preparing Backup"; can't mount .sparsebundle file

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine, nas

I've twice now tried to initiate a TimeMachine backup, and both times they got stuck during the "Preparing Backup..." stage. I think even on the same file, as shown in `tmutil status` which got stuck both times when processing file `1117289`. I've restarted the computer.

According to some [support links](https://soundsupport.biz/2016/10/23/deleting-incomplete-time-machine-backups/) on the web, I should try to get rid of the `.inProgress` file on the TimeMachine backup server. From what I understand, it's [located](http://pondini.org/TM/A10.html) in the `.sparsebundle` file corresponding to my backup.

However, opening the contents of the sparsebundle, I do not see it. When I instead try mounting the sparsebundle, I get the following Finder error message:

> Image: my-backup.sparsebundle | Reason: Resource temporarily unavilable

I'm not sure what the issue is here. I'm running TimeMachine on a Synology NAS on the network. Running macOS 10.12.4.